# Change cursor Color in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am using the `Textbox` option of the `Fabric.js` library.

Is it possible to change the color of the `cursor` in the `textbox`. If the `textbox` is placed on a dark image, I can make the text appear a bit clear by easily changing the font color but its not at all easy to even locate where the cursor is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is very much possible. This is what you need:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
var text = new fabric.Textbox('Hellow wordld is a  textbox in one line', {
            width:250,
            cursorColor :"blue"
        });
canvas.add(text)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://fabricjs.com/lib/fabric.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLdng24p/12/) Link. Code wont work here properly. Check the fiddle for the demo. Basically you have to add a property as `cursorColor` while creating Fabric Textbox and it will do what you want.

Comment: @Stephan Good for you in my system the embedded snippet was not working thats why added a Fiddle. And if this solved you question you mark it as an answer.